# What does the rectangular symbol means in mathematica??

Tags: inequality, mathematica

I was solving a problem related to inequality and there I get this root but I didn't get what does this rectangular symbol means ?

[image: Image of the root and also symbol]

The code for the mathematica is --

```
Reduce [10 p^3 (1 - p)^2 + 5 p^4 (1 - p) + p^3 < p, p]
```

Comment: It simply represents the variable in a polynomial. Using `#`, `#1`, etc, prevents conflicts with other variable names the user may have (or could later) define. It's officially called a ["Slot"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html).

Comment: Sorry but didn't get that what does it mean by 1+ #1 - 10#1^2 ?? Can you please explain it more clearly?

Comment: `1+#1-10#1^2` just means the polynomial that might otherwise be written as "$1+x-10x^2$". Mathematica uses `#n` to represent its own variable names, leaving letters (and letter sequences) available to us humans. (There are some technical details about how Mathematica uses these symbols —and the trailing `&`— to represent "pure functions" and whatnot, but that's the gist.) ... Anyway, you'd probably get a more-informative response by posting your question to [Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks I got it now